# Module parse failed: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' (1:0)

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs, ecmascript-5

I need help with this error I have not much experience with babel when I am trying to run the JS app it throws this error. I have went through various solutions but I could not resolve it. When I remove `"./src/index.js"` from webpack config error goes away but the app does not function. Does anyone know the solution?

```
  ERROR in ./node_modules/@babel/runtime/regenerator/index.js 1:0
Module parse failed: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' (1:0)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
> import _typeof from "@babel/runtime/helpers/typeof";
| 
| // TODO(Babel 8): Remove this file.
 @ ./src/index.js 3:0-61 19:54-78 21:11-35 66:61-85 67:9-33

ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:
  Module parse failed: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' (1:0)
  File was processed with these loaders:
   * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  > import _typeof from "@babel/runtime/helpers/typeof";
  | 
  | // TODO(Babel 8): Remove this file.:
  SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' (1:0)
  ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' (1:0)
  File was processed with these loaders:
   * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  > import _typeof from "@babel/runtime/helpers/typeof";
  | 
  | // TODO(Babel 8): Remove this file.
  
  - NormalModule.js:976 handleParseError
    [wolf3d-readyplayerme-threejs-boilerplate]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModule.js:976:19
  
 

ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:
  Module parse failed: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' (1:0)
  File was processed with these loaders:
   * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  > import _typeof from "@babel/runtime/helpers/typeof";
  | 
  | // TODO(Babel 8): Remove this file.:
  SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' (1:0)
  ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' (1:0)
  File was processed with these loaders:
   * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  > import _typeof from "@babel/runtime/helpers/typeof";
  | 
  | // TODO(Babel 8): Remove this file.
  
  - NormalModule.js:976 handleParseError
    [wolf3d-readyplayerme-threejs-boilerplate]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModule.js:976:19

  - child-compiler.js:131 
    [wolf3d-readyplayerme-threejs-boilerplate]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/child-compiler.js:131:18
  
  - Compiler.js:551 finalCallback
    [wolf3d-readyplayerme-threejs-boilerplate]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:551:5
  

1 ERROR in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)
webpack 5.74.0 compiled with 4 errors and 11 warnings in 16857 ms
```

Here is my webpack.config.js file

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = (env) => {
  const isProd = env && env.prod;
  const config = {
    mode: isProd ? "production" : "development",
    performance: { hints: false },
    entry: ["babel-polyfill", "./src/index.js"],
    plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        DEVELOPMENT: !isProd,
      }),
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        process: 'process/browser',
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: "./src/index.js",
      }),
      new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: [{ from: "src/assets", to: "assets" }],
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        title: isProd ? "Production" : "Development",
        meta: {
          viewport:
            "width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no",
        },
      }),
    ],
    output: {
      filename: "[name].js",
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    },
    resolve: {
      fallback: {
        util: require.resolve("util/")
      }
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(glsl|vs|fs|vert|frag)$/,
          use: ["raw-loader", "glslify-loader"],
        },
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          use: {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {
              compact: false,
              presets: [["@babel/preset-env"]],
              plugins: [
                ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime', { "regenerator": true } ],
                "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining",
                "@babel/plugin-syntax-nullish-coalescing-operator",
              ],
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  };

  if (!isProd) {
    config.devtool = "eval";
  }

  return config;
};
```

Comment: Do you have a babel config file? What about a browserslist config? What is your desired compilation target for babel/webpack? You are using deprecated `babel-polyfill` and `process/browser`, should update those to modern approaches. If you explicitly set a compilation `target` in babel or webpack configs, and remove the `ProvidePlugin` for `process/browser` your error might go away. I think `process/browser` is setting the `sourceType` to `script` without specifying a specific  compilation `target`. Also, why not show `./src/index.js`?

Comment: You also have `@babel/preset-env` in an unnecessary nested array, can just be `presets: ['@babel/preset-env']`, although you could specify a `target` config value here.

Answer (score -1):

Changing `typeof x` to `typeof(x)` seems to fix it.

Has to do something with babel and this line:

`import _typeof from "@babel/runtime/helpers/typeof`

Maybe the configuration file is missing something?

Edit : Adding `sourceType: 'unambiguous',` to the options of webpack configuration file to the babel-loader fixes it. You might have to edit babel.config if you manage options there.